# No puedo ejectura el codigo javascript en un archivo jsx

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend

tardes o noches. Tengo un ligero problema con respecto a algo con NextJS. Estoy usando esto para el FrontEnd de una página web, pero el caso es que decidí utilizar un diseño para un sidebar que vi en YouTube.
El caso es que el código viene a ser este:

El código del video:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sidebar With Bootstrap</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.lineicons.com/4.0/lineicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <aside id="sidebar">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <button class="toggle-btn" type="button">
                    <i class="lni lni-grid-alt"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="sidebar-logo">
                    <a href="#">CodzSword</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                        <i class="lni lni-user"></i>
                        <span>Profile</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                        <i class="lni lni-agenda"></i>
                        <span>Task</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-link collapsed has-dropdown" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#auth" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="auth">
                        <i class="lni lni-protection"></i>
                        <span>Auth</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="auth" class="sidebar-dropdown list-unstyled collapse" data-bs-parent="#sidebar">
                        <li class="sidebar-item">
                            <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Login</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sidebar-item">
                            <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Register</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-link collapsed has-dropdown" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#multi" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multi">
                        <i class="lni lni-layout"></i>
                        <span>Multi Level</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="multi" class="sidebar-dropdown list-unstyled collapse" data-bs-parent="#sidebar">
                        <li class="sidebar-item">
                            <a href="#" class="sidebar-link collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                data-bs-target="#multi-two" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multi-two">
                                Two Links
                            </a>
                            <ul id="multi-two" class="sidebar-dropdown list-unstyled collapse">
                                <li class="sidebar-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Link 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="sidebar-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Link 2</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                        <i class="lni lni-popup"></i>
                        <span>Notification</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                        <i class="lni lni-cog"></i>
                        <span>Setting</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="sidebar-footer">
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                    <i class="lni lni-exit"></i>
                    <span>Logout</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </aside>
        <div class="main p-3">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h1>
                    Sidebar Bootstrap 5
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

El CSS del archivo es este:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap');

::after,
::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.main {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #fafbfe;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 70px;
    min-width: 70px;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #0e2238;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#sidebar.expand {
    width: 260px;
    min-width: 260px;
}

.toggle-btn {
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}

.toggle-btn i {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #FFF;
}

.sidebar-logo {
    margin: auto 0;
}

.sidebar-logo a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#sidebar:not(.expand) .sidebar-logo,
#sidebar:not(.expand) a.sidebar-link span {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 2rem 0;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

a.sidebar-link {
    padding: .625rem 1.625rem;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
}

.sidebar-link i {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin-right: .75rem;
}

a.sidebar-link:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .075);
    border-left: 3px solid #3b7ddd;
}

.sidebar-item {
    position: relative;
}

#sidebar:not(.expand) .sidebar-item .sidebar-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 70px;
    background-color: #0e2238;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 15rem;
    display: none;
}

#sidebar:not(.expand) .sidebar-item:hover .has-dropdown+.sidebar-dropdown {
    display: block;
    max-height: 15em;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

#sidebar.expand .sidebar-link[data-bs-toggle="collapse"]::after {
    border: solid;
    border-width: 0 .075rem .075rem 0;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1.5rem;
    top: 1.4rem;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

#sidebar.expand .sidebar-link[data-bs-toggle="collapse"].collapsed::after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
```

Cree un componente llamado sidebartest.jsx, funciona y así lo tengo, usando el Bootstrap y bueno, el código CSS ya está incluido en el global.css del proyecto y funciona:

```
function Sidebartest() {
    return (
      <div class="wrapper">
          <aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <button id="toggle-btn" type="button">
                        <i class="lni lni-grid-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="sidebar-logo">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                          <i class="lni lni-user"></i>
                          <span>Profile</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                          <i class="lni lni-user"></i>
                          <span>Roles</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                          <i class="lni lni-license"></i>
                          <span>Permission</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                          <i class="lni lni-user"></i>
                          <span>Users</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                          <i class="lni lni-tab"></i>
                          <span>Categories</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
  
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                      <a href="#" class="sidebar-link has-dropdown collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#team" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="team">
                          <i class="lni lni-user"></i>
                          <span>Teams</span>
                      </a>
                      <ul id="team" class="sidebar-dropdow list-unstyled collapse" data-bs-parent="#sidebar">
                          <li class="sidebar-item">
                              <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Teams</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="sidebar-item">
                              <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Players</a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
  
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                      <a href="#" class="sidebar-link has-dropdown collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#tournament" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="tournament">
                          <i class="lni lni-game"></i>
                          <span>Tournaments</span>
                      </a>
                      <ul id="tournament" class="sidebar-dropdow list-unstyled collapse" data-bs-parent="#sidebar">
                          <li class="sidebar-item">
                              <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Tournaments</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="sidebar-item">
                              <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Matches</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="sidebar-item">
                              <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Match results</a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
  
  
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                          <i class="lni lni-user"></i>
                          <span>Clasifications</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                          <i class="lni lni-paypal"></i>
                          <span>Payment reasons</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                          <i class="lni lni-paypal"></i>
                          <span>Payments</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                          <i class="lni lni-paypal"></i>
                          <span>Transaction</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
  
  
  
                    <li class="sidebar-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                          <i class="lni lni-exit"></i>
                          <span>Logout</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
  export default Sidebartest
```

El problema con esto es que no sé cómo utilizar el script que aparece en dicho repositorio que es este:

```
const hamBurger = document.querySelector(".toggle-btn");

hamBurger.addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.querySelector("#sidebar").classList.toggle("expand");
});
```

Intente importarlo directamente al codigo del componente de esta forma:

```
function Sidebartest() {
    const hamBurger = document.querySelector(".toggle-btn");

    hamBurger.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelector("#sidebar").classList.toggle("expand");
    });
    return (
      <div class="wrapper">
          <aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <button id="toggle-btn" type="button">
                        <i class="lni lni-grid-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="sidebar-logo">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
    //Resto del codigo...
```

A lo que me dio este error:

```
⨯ components\sidebartest.jsx (2:22) @ document
 ⨯ ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Sidebartest (./components/sidebartest.jsx:9:23)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:338:14)
  1 | function Sidebartest() {
> 2 |     const hamBurger = document.querySelector(".toggle-btn");
    |                      ^
  3 |
  4 |     hamBurger.addEventListener("click", function () {
  5 |     document.querySelector("#sidebar").classList.toggle("expand");
```

Intente en utilizar otra forma que es hacerlo de un archivo "script.js", importarlo desde el layout o haciendo un "import '../../script'", pero tampoco funciona al final de cuenta. No he encontrado documentación o algún video que me explique cómo utilizar los JS o llegar a modificarlos para que funcionen como tal. Incluso utilice métodos como haciendo el script de esta forma:

```
export function initSidebarToggle() {
    if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
        const hamburger = document.querySelector("#toggle-btn");

        hamburger.addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.querySelector("#sidebar").classList.toggle("expand");
        });
    }
}
```

Eso no ayudo, ni modificando el codigo para que haga algo como:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { initSidebarToggle } from './script.js';

function Sidebartest() {
    useEffect(() => {
        initSidebarToggle();
    }, []); // Se ejecuta solo una vez al montar el componente

    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            {/* Contenido del sidebar aquí */}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Sidebartest;
```

Pero me arroja problemas como:

```
Error:
  × You're importing a component that needs useEffect. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
  │ Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials
  │
  │
   ╭─[C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\taking-the-game\components\sidebartest.jsx:1:1]
 1 │ import { useEffect } from 'react';
   ·          ─────────
 2 │ import { initSidebarToggle } from '../public/script';
 3 │
 3 │ function Sidebartest() {
   ╰────

Import trace for requested module:
./components/sidebartest.jsx
./src/app/home/page.jsx
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no se especifica lo contrario, todos los componentes en NextJS son [Server components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components), donde objetos específicos del lado del cliente como Window y Document no existen.

Una solución posible (desconozco si hay otras) es usar la directiva "use client" en el componente (o en un padre del componente) en la parte superior del archivo donde se encuentra el componente que queremos definir como un [Client Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components). Entonces el componente que usa la directiva "use client" y sus componentes hijos son definidos como del lado del cliente, se crea un ámbito que envuelve a todos esos nodos, y el objeto document y los hooks usados normalmente en react del lado del cliente como ***useEffect*** y ***useRef*** están disponibles.

El componente que estas queriendo implementar debería quedar así:

```
"use client"

import { useRef } from 'react';
import '../styles/sidebar.css'

export default function Sidebar() {

  const sidebarRef = useRef<HTMLElement|null>(null)

  const toggleSidebar = () => sidebarRef.current?.classList?.toggle('expand')
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <aside id="sidebar" ref={sidebarRef}>
          <div className="d-flex">
            <button className="toggle-btn" type="button" onClick={toggleSidebar}>
              <i className="lni lni-grid-alt"></i>
            </button>
            <div className="sidebar-logo">
              <a href="#">CodzSword</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* contenido del sidebar */}
        </aside>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
        crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
    </>
  )
}
```

En mi ejemplo use una [referencia](https://es.react.dev/reference/react/useRef) para manipular el nodo del dom, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198952/using-document-queryselector-in-react-should-i-use-refs-instead-how) tienes varias razones de porque eso es mejor que hacerlo al estilo VainillaJS.